# Missing 'uninitialized' warning

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Here is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    float v[n];
    float sum;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = i + 1;
        printf("v[%d]=%f\n", i, v[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += v[i]; //uninitialized using
    }

    printf("sum=%f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc compiles it without any warning of uninitialized variable.

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 with following options:

```
gcc -Wall  main.c -o main
```

What option should I use to get warning?

Comment: Related - [Why does g++ warning about uninitialized variable depend on the type of the variable? (it warns for an int but not for a double)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996151/why-does-g-warning-about-uninitialized-variable-depend-on-the-type-of-the-vari)

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I don't think that's the right duplicate.

Comment: You might find something useful in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550115/inconsistent-results-c/12550720#12550720). Though it boils down to the same answer Jens posted below.

Comment: @staticx You're right. I retracted my close vote and left the comment only as a link to a related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the -O (optimize) option; value tracking is only performed on optimized code.

```
$ gcc -Wall -O x.c
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:15: warning: ‘sum’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to @Jens answer, if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O` you will see more warnings:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O -o main main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable-size array 'v'
main.c:15:20: warning: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
main.c:15:20: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
main.c:15: warning: 'sum' is used uninitialized in this function
```